# Single member pointers in OOP

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, member-pointers

Im a student and I faced a problem to understand the concept of single member pointers in object-orianted-programming (OOP) and I searched a lot on Google but did not got the idea!

Can you help me understanding it in details please?

Comment: Do you mean: `class Foo { int* a; };` that?

Comment: @DynamicSquid I don't realy have any idea about it.. Can you explain it by general what it is

Comment: I'm reasonably proficient with C++ (if I may say so myself), and I've never heard the term "single member pointers". Where did you see that? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I had it in my class and I did not understood what teacher is saying!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Do you mean pointers that are members inside a class?

Comment: @DynamicSquid yes please

Comment: Well, do you know what a class is?

Comment: @DynamicSquid yes of course

Answer (score -1):

So after further clarification from the comments, you seem to be wondering about pointer members in a class, like this:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
  int* a;
};
```

Now pointers in classes are basically the same as normal variables, but since you are dealing with memory here, you will be 3 additional things ([Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#:%7E:text=The%20rule%20of%20three%20(also,copy%20assignment%20operator))):

1. Destructor
2. Copy Constructor
3. overloaded `operator=`

I won't go too much into detail here, but it should look something like this:

```cpp
class Foo
{
private:
  int a*;

public:
  ~Foo() // destructor
  {
    delete a;
  }

  Foo(const Foo& cpy) // copy constructor
    : a(cpy.a) {}

  Foo& operator=(const Foo& cpy) // assignment
  {
    a = copy.a;
  }
};
```

Please learn about those three, called the Rule of Three, before you move on with pointers as attributes in a class.

And whenever you find yourself using pointers inside a class, you need to implement the Rule of Three.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Problem with this answer is that it is not a good implementation of the rule of three. This code would cause multiple deletion problems.

Comment: What do you mean by that?